# How can I catch an error in a sequencial cascade Observables?

Tags: angular, observable

When you want to catch an error for the subscribe callback, you can use its second parameter and intercept a `HttpErrorResponse` for example:

```
this.service.service1().subscribe(
    (result) => {...},
    (err: HttpErrorResponse) => { error handling }
);
```

but how can you catch the same error when it occurs instead in the `switchMap` of a cascade `Observables`?

Let's say that an `HttpErrorResponse` error occurs after getting res2 in the following example. Where and how is that handled? How can I make sure that `this.service.service3(res2)` (and potentially other services that will come after) won't be executed?

```
this.service.service1().pipe(
    switchMap((res1) => this.service.service2(res1)),
    switchMap((res2) => {
       this.ex = res2;
       return this.service.service3(res2);
    })
).subscribe((res3) => {
    // Do something with res3.
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RxJS does that for you. Here's a quick demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-observable-error. As you can see the first two observables successfully trigger the `tap()` meanwhile, after switching to the third one (error observable) `tap()` doesn't get triggered anymore and it jumps directly to the `subscribe()`
Note: `catchError()` could be used in the pipe aswell after an error-prone switchMap to prevent complete failure.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cleanest solution is to convert your stream like following using MergeMap operator:

```js
import { of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

const service2 = val =>
  of(`${val} service 2 call\n`);

const service3 = val => of(`${val} service 3 call`)

const serviceError = val => throwError('Error');

const service1$ = of('service 1 call \n');


service1$
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(val => service2(val)),
    mergeMap(val => serviceError(val)),
    mergeMap(val => service3(val))
  )
  // output: 'Error'
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val), err => console.log(err));

// The call of serviceError will throw an error so stream will be down.
// If you change the serviceError implementation to return a  of('service 1 call \n'); everything will be ok and the stream will work

import { of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';


const service2 = val =>
  of(`${val} service 2 call\n`);

const service3 = val => of(`${val} service 3 call`)

const service1$ = of('service 1 call \n');


service1$
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(val => service2(val)),
    mergeMap(val => service3(val))
  )
  // output: 'service 1 call '
  //         'service 2 call'
 //            'service 3 call'
  .subscribe(val => console.log(val), err => console.log(err));
```

the example on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-dvs3ys)